Run C# custom actions of msi when .net framework is not present using Wix toolset
Our msi has some custom actions which require .NET 4.7.2. But if the user does not have that version of .NET installed, the custom action throws an exception

Failed to get requested CLR info. Error code 0x80131700

I tried to include WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_472_OR_LATER_INSTALLED this in the launch condition but if the user needs the older version of .NET for some other application then they can't install this version so is there a way to include the runtime dependency in the custom action.

The following may be of interest: Building Installation Package Bundles
